# I study abstract algebra mainly because I'm planning to study relativity Please give me a guideline for learning this subject

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not duplicating [how to study abstract algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565890/how-to-study-abstract-algebra). I recently downloaded Herstein's Abstract algebra and there are many contents in the book and I actually want to know if I need to read through all of the chapters if I learn it just for relativity. And what are the connections between physics and abstract algebra apart from relativity? If the purpose is to have a better understanding of physics, to which degree should one dig into this?

Comment: There are tight connections between (operator) algebra and quantum dynamics as well. The entire comcept of $C^*$-algebras originated from a desire to better understand the mathematical properties of observable quantities.